# Class 'Threaded' not found

Tags: php

I am experimenting with multi threading in PHP.
Im using php 5.6, however l have downloaded extensions for this version of php,
namely : pthreadVC2.dll, php_pthreads.dll
I have also edited my php.ini file by adding the following lines:

```
extension=php_pthreads.dll
extension=pthreadVC2.dll
```

but l am still getting the error: Class 'Threaded' not found. Am l missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Write a short script to check that your extension has loaded. http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901578/php-pthreads-fatal-error-class-thread-not-found

Comment: @bamber box, thank you its not loaded. I think l'll got thru e php 5.6 versions till l find the one that works.

Comment: @Abu, thanks, it seems lm on the right track, just that my extension hasnt been loaded, it may not be for this version of 5.6.