# php why I get Class 'Thread' not found

Tags: php, multithreading, dll, php-pthread

I am using php version 7 and defined a class that extend Thread class but when I run My Program that give me Class 'Thread' not found  error.I searched and I found out I must copy `pthreadVC2.dll` in apache and system32 folders and copy `php_pthreads.dll` in php/ext and system32 folders and add `extension=php_pthreads.dll` to `php.ini` .I did all these works but I get that error again.`php_pthreads.dll` and `pthreadVC2.dll` version is 14

```
<?php
class exampleThread extends Thread
{
    var  $Mobile;
    var  $code;
    public function __construct($Mobile, $code)
    {
        $this->Mobile = $Mobile;
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    public function run()
    {

    }
};
?>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @urfusion I edited

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901578/php-pthreads-fatal-error-class-thread-not-found

Comment: @urfusion Not a duplicate. The situation has changed significantly since PHP 5.5.

Comment: @duskwuff : I has not raise a duplicate flag. It just for reference. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The pthreads extension cannot be used in a web server environment.](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php) It is only available in the CLI.

Whatever you're trying to do, you'll need to come up with another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer from [duskwuff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149341/duskwuff), the pthreads extension [cannot be used in a web server environment](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php).

We were *playing* around for about 1 week and unfortunately had to realize that running it in the CLI version leads to too many issues once it becomes too complicated --> we stopped and removed `pthreads` from our environment.

**What I can suggest you:**
Due to the fact we still need a multi-threaded functionality we were checking several methods and *ended* up using [curl multi functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php).

With curl multi functions you achieve a full multi-threading execution - and especially in our case - when you got lot of cores [we have 48] you can indeed use all of them when you *spawn* your tasks with curl...

The PHP curl multi exec documentation is very poor. I refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559157/understanding-php-curl-multi-exec) where you get additional information.