# PHP pthreads installation problem with php

Tags: php, pthreads, wampserver, php-ini, server-configuration

I work with PHP 5.6.40, trying to install php_threads 2.0.10.
I follow the subject [PHP pthreads: Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901578/php-pthreads-fatal-error-class-thread-not-found/57178150)

I work with wampserver.

Apache Version : 2.4.39

PHP Version : 5.6.40

I copy php_threads on /php/ext of the php version

```
copy pthreadVC2.dll on /php

copy pthreadVC2.dll on /apache

copy pthreadVC2.dll on windows/system32

copy pthreadVC2.dll on windows/SysWow64
```

When i try to use i have this Fatal error:

> Class 'Threader' not found

and when i do`php.exe --re phpthread` I get:

> Exception: Extension phpthreads does not exist

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I find the problem,

On Wampserver, I have 2 php.ini used one by php and one by wampserver.

I edited only the wampserver php.ini file where I add `extension=php_pthreads`

When I edited the second one, that was super green, i can do some thread.

I hope that will be help you.