Running issue in pthread
when I run this code it's shows

Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found

even I followed all these step when i download
I copied pthreadVC2.dll to:
D:/xampp/php

And I copied last file php_pthreads.dll to:
D:/xampp/ext

I added to php.ini line with:
extension=php_pthreads.dll

My config:
XAMPP on Windows 10
PHP Version 7.0.30
Compiler: MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2017)
Architecture: x86
Thread Safety is enabled
Thread API is Windows Threads
php_pthreads-3.1.2-7.0-ts-vc14-x86 downloaded
<?php
// Enable error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class ApicallThreads extends Thread {
    private $apicallId;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->apicallId = $id;
    }

    public function run() {
        sleep(rand(0, 3));
        $ch = curl_init();
        $curlConfig = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "",
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array()
        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo nl2br("Thread call with the ID {$this->apicallId} ran\n\n");
    }
}

$apicalls = [];

for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $apicalls[$i] = new ApicallThreads($i);
    $apicalls[$i]->start();
}

foreach (range(0, 5) as $i) {
    $apicalls[$i]->join();
}
?>

So how to resolve this error

Have you seen the CAUTION on this page? Maybe that is the cause? Using Linux here, so no experience with Windows.

"PHP Version 7.0.30" - this version is horribly outdated. Did you check whether phpinfo() lists the extension as enabled? According to the Github repository of that extension, it requires PHP 7.2 or later

yes its enabled

"when I run this code" - can you also share "this code"?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901578/php-pthreads-fatal-error-class-thread-not-found I used this code for checking purpose

Please add all clarification, including the code you are using and your debugging attempts, to your question by editing it

I copied pthreadVC2.dll to:
D:/xampp/php
D:/xampp/apache/bin
And I copied last file php_pthreads.dll to:
D:/xampp/ext
I added to php.ini line with:
extension=php_pthreads.dll  then after  create  a folder and run this the above code but  it gave an error class thread not found

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. I would still assume that you haven't enabled the extension properly. How did you ensure that is actually is enabled?

I Check in phpinfo  then thread safety enabled but zend signal handling disable actually i m new in php so i don't much more about that

I used version php version 7.0.30 and vc14

If you are new in PHP, why did you install PHP v7.0.30 which is six years old and pthreads v3.1.5 which is more than eight years old? Wouldn't it be easier to start your journey with current versions? Also, the main question remains: how did you check that the extension is also enabled? Having thread safety enabled is a basic feature of PHP, not of the extension

I check using this  which extension you wants to know that was enabled or not

Well, you wanted to use the pthreads extension, so why not check whether that exact extension is enabled?

E:\7.1\xampp
php --ri pthreads
pthreads
Version => 3.1.2
it showed

That's the shell version of PHP. Did you also check this through using phpinfo() through a web request?

yes it shows enabled

"pthreads Version => 3.1.2" - didn't you tell earlier that you've installed v3.1.5?

yes i said but it won't work thats why i installed this but the same problem occur so actually i want to know that  how to resolve this

Did you try to use a more current version of PHP and of that extension?
